# Reserving Desktop Space so maximized windows don't cover it

Tags: windows, screen, maximize

I'd like to "reserve" a portion of the screen so that maximized windows don't cover that area (think taskbar(Win) or dock(mac).

I've seen other programs that have done this, but really have not liked them and since I'm in the business, thought I might have a hand at it... at least for my personal use.

I prefer to use a VS supported language, but if it can be done via Java or other, that's fine too - just more opportunity to learn :)

Does anybody know of a way to do this or a good reference on this issue?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/csdoesshell3.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

see MSDN C sample (SHAPP) which does exactly that (codeproject sample is just a poor copy..)